# How to bypass the username as a required field in registration and just use email address instead?

Tags: user-registration, wp-login-form, signup, wp-signup

Is there a clean way of doing so? I would prefer doing that in functions.php using some action and/ or filter hooks. The 2nd-best option would be using some good plugin out there. (I haven't seen 1 suitable though)

I can always generate random and unique strings to be usernames in the registration forms and just hide it with CSS. I would imagine meddling with wp-login.php but that would be so ugly.

I am able to let users log in using email address and password, but not username now, partly referencing [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51678/how-to-login-with-email-only-no-username). However, username still appears as a required field on the registration page which confuses people.

**Updates**
I've found that Register Plus Redux handles the login using email address instead of username well. However, I need to be able to modify the labels and texts on the registration page too (I need to put in Thai). It looks like there's no clean way but one will have to edit the codes in the plugins directly

Comment: Register Plus Redux support translation via standard po/mo files. You can translate the plugin in tour language using [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) or the [codestyling localization plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/)

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

*The registration and login forms* can be customized easily below a diggest from the codex:

**[Customizing The Registration Form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form)**

> Theme and plugin developers can customize WordPress's built-in user
>   registration page through the use of hooks.
>
> Customizing the registration form involves utilizing the following
>   three hooks:
>
> 1. register_form
>      Allows rendering of new HTML form elements.
> 2. registration_errors
>      Perform validation on form registration fields.
> 3. user_register
>      Save custom form data.

**[Customizing the Login Form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form)**

> You can customize your WordPress login page with action hooks and
>   filter hooks, including:
>
> - Actions in the  of the document: login_enqueue_scripts, login_head.
> - Filters in the : login_headerurl, login_headertitle, login_message, login_errors.
> - Actions at the bottom of and below the form: login_form, login_footer.

To additionally inform yourself about the above mentioned hooks take a look at the codex page about the [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API), you will find the hooks at the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and the [Filter Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference). Some additional, not mentioned hooks can be found at [Adminstrative Actions Section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) especially. Not all of the hooks are documented well (or at all), so it might be necessary to take a look at the source.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the "[WP Email Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-email-login/)"-plugin? It should solve your problem.

Comment: As far as I can see, that plugin only handles login, and not Registration form.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a plugin to handle Login, Registration and Retrieve Password using email only. Check out [Smart WP Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-wp-login/).