# I want login using email not username wordpress front end

Tags: login, authentication

For the login, I want to enable the user to use the email instead of the username. This is what I got so far:

```
remove_filter('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20);
function login_with_email_address($username) {
    $user = get_user_by_email($username);
    if(!empty($user->user_login))
        $username = $user->user_login;
    return $username;
}
add_action('wp_authenticate','login_with_email_address');
```

The result of this, is the following error message:

> "Invalid username or password. Please try again!"

Comment: OK. So you have task and a code. What is missing? What is the problem?

Comment: yes @Robert hue i  don't know what is missing with added code because above code i have added in function.php wordpress theme file,
i simple want user can login with email id not using username please help me about this

Comment: Yes, we understand that you added this code in `functions.php` file but then what is the problem? What is your question? Are you getting any error? Explain your issue.

Comment: When i add code 
remove_filter('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20);
 
with below code then i got error message,message is "Invalid username or password. Please try again!"

`remove_filter('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20);
function login_with_email_address($username) {
    $user = get_user_by_email($username);
    if(!empty($user->user_login))
        $username = $user->user_login;
    return $username;
}
add_action('wp_authenticate','login_with_email_address');`

Comment: If you have another hook or concept please give me solution for login using email id not username

Comment: Possible answer here. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/149410

Comment: thanks for giving above url but i also used code like

// remove the default filter
remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3 );
// add custom filter
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'fb_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3 );
function fb_authenticate_username_password( $user, $username, $password ) {

    
    return wp_authenticate_username_password( NULL, $username, $password );
}

but it is working for username not for email
after added code when we login from email then it give error message "Invalid username or password. Please try again!"

Comment: @user3811650 Please file an **[edit]** to your question instead of pasting code into comments. The lack of format there explains quite verbose that this is the wrong place for updates :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to login with email only no username?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51678/how-to-login-with-email-only-no-username)

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some problems:

- You are using deprecated function `get_user_by_email`
- You are using wrong hook `wp_authenticate`

You can this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-email-login/

or

Your can use this code

```
function wpsc_authenticate_user_by_email( $user, $username, $password ) {


    // Bailout
    if( ! is_frontend_login_form() ){
       return $user;
    }

    $login_page  = strtok( $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], '?' );

    //check for valid inputs
    if( $username == "" || $password == "" ) {
        wp_redirect( $login_page . "?login=empty" );
        exit;
    }

    // get user by email
    if ( is_email( $username ) ) {
        $user =  get_user_by( 'email', $username );

        // validate user
        if ( $user && wp_check_password( $password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID ) ) {
            return $user;
        }else{
            wp_redirect( $login_page . '?login=failed' );
            exit;
        }
    }else{
        wp_redirect( $login_page . '?login=failed' );
        exit;
    }


    return $user;
}

add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wpsc_authenticate_user_by_email', 1, 3 );
```

Define conditions in `is_frontend_login_form()` to check if user is coming from your frontend form or not.

Comment: Thanks @Ravs for giving url and codes but when i add above given code in my theme file then website not running my be i added in wroung way can you explain me how to add code and where we have to add  above code

and also where we have to apply is_frontend_login_form(