# Overriding WP login credentials

Tags: php, wp-login-form

Whenever we login to wpadmin there are two available credentials

1. username or email
2. password

I want phone number in place of username so I can login to wpadmin with

1. Phone Number or Email
2. password

Is there any possibility to override WP credentials ?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you storing the admin user phone numbers? I don't think that's a standard field. Are you using phone-based 2FA like Duo Security?

Comment: Essentially you want to make a copy of the wp_authenticate_email_password function in wp-includes/user.php, which is more or less Pullata's answer, but that looks up the user by phone number instead, and then register it as an additional 'authenticate' filter. How exactly you do that depends on how you're storing the phone number in the first place. You probably want to normalize the phone number first e.g. using libphonenumber-for-php, provided you stored it that way too.

Comment: for test purpose i am storing phone number in an additional field which i created in wp_user database

Answer (score 1):

If you would do changes with the core files of wordpress , the changes will be lost on a next upgrade of wordpress.

And if you want to edit the login.php you need to create a custom function which will override the default function (which is using for 'UserName')

You can follow this link

[How to login with email only no username?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51678/how-to-login-with-email-only-no-username)

Comment: thanks @mukii kumar for the answer but i want to log in with phone number and email to WP.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing we need to do is remove the default authentication rights. Add the following snippet to your functions.php file:

```
//remove wordpress authentication
remove_filter('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20);
```

Add the following code to your functions.php files:

```
add_filter('authenticate', function($user, $email, $password){

//Check for empty fields
    if(empty($email) || empty ($password)){        
        //create new error object and add errors to it.
        $error = new WP_Error();

        if(empty($email)){ //No email
            $error->add('empty_username', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Email field is empty.'));
        }
        else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //Invalid Email
            $error->add('invalid_username', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Email is invalid.'));
        }

        if(empty($password)){ //No password
            $error->add('empty_password', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Password field is empty.'));
        }

        return $error;
    }

    //Check if user exists in WordPress database
    $user = get_user_by('email', $email);

    //bad email
    if(!$user){
        $error = new WP_Error();
        $error->add('invalid', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Either the email or password you entered is invalid.'));
        return $error;
    }
    else{ //check password
        if(!wp_check_password($password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID)){ //bad password
            $error = new WP_Error();
            $error->add('invalid', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Either the email or password you entered is invalid.'));
            return $error;
        }else{
            return $user; //passed
        }
    }
}, 20, 3);
```

The code checks if the username (now email) or password fields are empty. If neither are empty, it uses `get_user_by` to look for the user’s email. After finding a valid user, it then checks if the password is correct using the `wp_check_password()` function.

For further details [Click Here](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/email-login/?hpv=b&utm_expid=3606929-74.aeX0WyvtRVa7qMe8Ph5smw.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F)

Comment: the above code is for validating purpose where in normal login credentials validating is for user name but here you will get for email

Comment: thanks @pullata parveen for the answer but my question still remain the same that i want to use phone number and email to login to WP.

Comment: OK, but WordPress 4.5 supports login with email address out-of-the-box.